# Is it possible to configure hdfs in a federation mode and in an HA mode in the same time?

Tags: high-availability, hadoop, distributed-filesystems, hdfs, federated

I don't understand if it possible to configure HDFS in both modes in the same time. Does it make sense? Can somebody show a simple configuration of HDFS in both modes? (nameNode1, nameNode2, nameNodeStandby1, nameNodeStandby2)